# How to show Enum type members in a DataGridViewComboBox?

Tags: c#, datagridview, enums

What else I have to do in order to show `ReadAccess` enum members in this DatagridViewComboBox?

```
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Clear();
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.AddRange(ReadAccess.None, ReadAccess.Allowed);
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(ReadAccess);
```

here is designer-generated codes about DataGridView:

```
this.rolesDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.rolesDataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
this.TableNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn,
this.WriteDataGridViewComboBoxColumn,
this.ReadCodeDataGridViewComboBoxColumn,
this.ProcessDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn,
this.AdministrateDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn});
this.rolesDataGridView.DataSource = this.bsTablePermissions;
```

and finally, in after `InitializeComponent();`, i'm setting DataGridView's DataSource:

```
this.rolesDataGridView.DataSource = this.RoleTablePermissions;  // a bindingsource list
```

Comment: Have you done `this.Controls.Add(ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn)` or similar?

Comment: @George: yes, sure... but when i run the project, the combo box is frozen and i can't open it's list...

Comment: Is there more code to instantiate the DataGridView than just this?

Comment: Just designer generated codes... let me put them here...

Comment: Try subscribing to the DataGridView.DataError event and check of there's an error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a problem i've come across many times. The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` doesn't know how to reconcile the difference between the enum's string representation and its integral value. Even though you set `ValueType` to the type of the enum, the `DataGridView` will try to set the cell's value to the underlying `int` value - this is why a `FormatException` will be raised during databinding.

The only way i've found to overcome this problem (short of subclassing the cell type) is to bind the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a data source which separates the string values from the integer values. You can use an anonymous type for this purpose:

```
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(ReadAccess);
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "Value";
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Display";
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = new ReadAccess[]
    { ReadAccess.None, ReadAccess.Allowed }
    .Select(value => new { Display=value.ToString(), Value=(int)value })
    .ToList();
```

This way, the `DataGridView` knows how to relate the cell value with its formatted value.

Comment: @Bradley: I still have problems with this... The Combo box is still frozen and i can't open the list and also, i receive `FormatException`...

Comment: @Dr TJ: Is it possible that one of the other columns in your `DataGridView` is causing the problem, now that you've fixed this one? Check the `ColumnIndex` property in your handler for the `DataError` event.

Comment: @Bradley: I did what you said and the error is on all columns containing combo box...

Comment: @Dr TJ: I can't see why it isn't working... Check the `Value` of one of the affected cells (in the event handler) - is it set to the enum value or an `int`? In all cases, it was an `int` when I tried.

Comment: @Bradley, Yes this is an Int32 value... but what can i do with this?

Comment: The `DataGridView` should automatically look-up the enum value which corresponds to the int value, by referring to the `ValueMember` property of the column. Are you sure that each `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` has its `DataSource` property set to a list of anonymous objects as outlined in my answer? It will not work if you add to the `Items` collection.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to the answer Bradly Smith provided: One can get all Enum values (instead of naming each individually) easily using this code:

```
    ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource =
        new List<ReadAccess>((ReadAccess[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReadAccess)))
        .Select(value => new { Display=value.ToString(), Value=(int)value })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not convert enum value to the int. Use this code if you have an error like "invalid value":

```
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = new ReadAccess[]
{ ReadAccess.None, ReadAccess.Allowed }
.Select(value => new { Display=value.ToString(), Value=value })
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

An Improvement to accepted answer:
There is no need to type enum members as array manually. Instead you can use `System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReadAccess))`. *Also, instead of anonymous type list, you can use a **List from Dictionary*** (Dictionary isn't accepted as datasource):

```
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource= System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReadAccess))
  .Cast<Enum>.ToDictionary<string, Enum>((e) => e.ToString(), (e) =>  e).ToList;
```

*or directly a **KeyValuePair list** :*

```
ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReadAccess))
  .Cast<Enum>.Select((value) => new KeyValuePair<string, enum>(value.ToString(), (value)));
```

Still necessary (but DisplayMember now is "**Key**") :

```
 ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(ReadAccess);
 ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "Value";
 ReadDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Key";
```