# Simple alternative for DataGridView which supports enumerations

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I need something like DataGridView. It should be able to bind to the collection of the following objects:

```
class Register
{
   TypeEnum Type{get;set;}
   string Name{get;set;}
}
```

And it should display this collection and allow editing their properties: select desirable enum value  from the combobox and to enter Name in the textbox. Also, adding new objects and removing existing ones should be supported.

DataGridView doesn't fit because it doesn't support enums.
How this functionality can be achieved without too much manual coding?

EDIT: I tried using DataGridView for this purpose, but it is terrible. I can't add new rows or delete some without creating additional buttons with error-prone handlers. Is there any human way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this with DataGridView itself.

1) Create `dropdownbox for one column type` and bind it with `typeof(enum)`
[Create drop down list options from enum in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443/create-drop-down-list-options-from-enum-in-a-datagridview)

2) Use `TypeConverter of EnumConverter`
[Data bind enum properties to grid and display description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540103/data-bind-enum-properties-to-grid-and-display-description)

Few others,

[How to show Enum type members in a DataGridViewComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120838/how-to-show-enum-type-members-in-a-datagridviewcombobox)

[How to display enum values in datagridview column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924257/how-to-display-enum-values-in-datagridview-column)

Comment: If I follow this way, I can't use dataGrid.Datasource = source; And all synchronization for the data I will need to do manually, which is unacceptable.

Comment: If you figure this out better way, post your answer so community can benefit. as of now, no such things exists